# QGraphicsScene. How do I draw an ellipse over a loaded image in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene. On QGraphicsScene, I output the image using QGraphicsPixmapItem. And I would like to draw an ellipse over the image with my mouse.
I have that code now. And the ellipse is drawn on MainWindow.
What do I need to do to have the ellipse drawn on an image in QGraphicsView?

Code OFT_MainWindow

```
    # OFT_MainWindow

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(862, 710)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 841, 571))
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 670, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(760, 10, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 731, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 670, 331, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 841, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Highlight field area"))
```

Main code

```
import OFT_MainWindow  
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageQt, ImageEnhance
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = MainWindow()  
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()  
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QGraphicsView, QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.imageFrame)
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.show()
        
###################################################################################    

    def browse_file(self):
        self.lineEdit.clear() 
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Choose file")
        file = str(file[0])
        if file: 
            self.lineEdit.setText(file)   # добавить путь в lineEdit
#         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

###################################################################################
        
    def imageFrame(self):
        file = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.image = QPixmap(file)
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.image)
        scene.addItem(item)
        view = self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
#         self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 25))  
        qp.setBrush(br)   
        ellipse = qp.drawEllipse(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))
        coord_a = self.begin
        coord_a = str(coord_a)
        coord_a = coord_a[20:][:-1]
        coord_b = self.end
        coord_b = str(coord_b)
        coord_b = coord_b[20:][:-1]
        coord = ('begin = ' + coord_a + ' end = ' + coord_b)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(coord)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
        
###################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to paint something on a QGraphicsView, you have to add QGraphicsItem to its scene, otherwise you're making almost useless to crete a QGraphicsView to begin with.

One possible solution is to install an event filter on the scene, listen for mouse button events and draw an ellipse (using [QGraphicsEllipseItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsellipseitem.html)) on the scene if the first click is done within the contents of a QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Note that another possibility is to subclass from QGraphicsPixmapItem and implement its mouse events instead. It all depends on what you're going to do and what you're going to need from your program.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # ...
        self.ellipseItem = None

    def imageFrame(self):
        # ...
        scene.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            for item in self.graphicsView.scene().items(event.scenePos()):
                if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    self.reference = item
                    self.ellipseItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(item)
                    self.ellipseItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 25))
                    self.start = item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseMove and self.ellipseItem:
            end = self.reference.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
            self.ellipseItem.setRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.start, end))
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseRelease and self.ellipseItem:
            self.ellipseItem = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Note that subclassing your Main window from all those classes (`QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QGraphicsView, QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene`) is not only unnecessary and meaningless, but absolutely **WRONG**: multiple-inheritance subclassing should only be done when you know what you're inheriting from and why, otherwise, just *don't*. For Qt widgets that load from UI files, just subclass from the base widget class and the Ui.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. From the program I need that when drawing an ellipse on an image, the coordinates of its beginning and end are displayed in "lineEdit_2". But now I get an error message: `TypeError: invalid result from MainWindow. eventFilter(), a 'bool' is expected not 'NoneType'`  What do I have to do to correct this error?

Comment: I seem to have fixed this error by adding `return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)`

Comment: Sorry, it went missing after copy&paste. I've updated the answer. To update the coordinates, just set those values in the event filter.

Comment: Thank you so much again. You've been a big help.